# Issues updating mingw

Tags: mingw

I'm trying to update mingw (version 6.3.0) through cmd but it doesn't work.

I tried using "mingw-get update" then "mingw-get upgrade" but it doesn't change the version. Any idea how to help me?

Answer (score 0):

MinGW 6.3.0 is really old.

I recommend switching to MinGW-w64, which is much more recent and supports both Windows 32-bit and 64-bit.

You can get it by installing [MSYS2](https://www.msys2.org/) and then installing it from it's package manager `pacman`.

Or you can just get the standalone build from https://winlibs.com/ which requires no installation.

Either way, if the old MinGW is configured in your system's `PATH` environment variable, you should remove it there first.